# Xcode 4.4 - Inline Assembly Issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, assembly, llvm, objective-c++

In Xcode 4.4 I am getting error when I try to build iOS project that has methods written in assembly. I am getting error "Inline Assembly Issue - invalid operand for instruction" for this line **vqrdmulh.s16 q2, q13**. 
I tried to compile with LLVM 4.0 and LLVM GCC 4.2 but I am getting the same error.
Project was compiling fine in previous version of Xcode.

Does someone know how to solve this error? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't vqrdmulh supposed to have 3 operands?

Comment: Third parameter was optional, but it seems that now is required.